# Formula Help: IF, Countif, Split. Override

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently running the following formula

```
=IF(P202="","",COUNTIF(SPLIT(P202," "),"*XXX*")+COUNTIF(SPLIT(P202," "),"*YYY*"))
```

This is to count the values XXX & YYY in column P. This returns values 0 - 4 primarily in column AC

However I have another column. Which is column W, in this column I have values such as 'cancelled' and 'postponed'.

What I would like to happen, as an example the above formula returns a value of 2 but if Column W was updated with cancelled. Then that value would alter the return to 0 as the event is now cancelled.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean: `=IF(W202="cancelled",0,IF(P202="","",COUNTIF(SPLIT(P202," "),"*XXX*")+COUNTIF(SPLIT(P202," "),"*YYY*")))`

Comment: Can you include a link to a worksheets with sample data?

Comment: @Rory This solution works for me. What I wanted to have multiple values? Not just cancelled but cancelled, postponed and dropped?

Comment: You could use: `=IF(OR(W202="cancelled",W202="postponed",W202="dropped"),0,IF(P202="","",COUNTIF(SPLIT(P202," "),"*XXX*")+COUNTIF(SPLIT(P202," "),"*YYY*")))`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(P202="",,SUM(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(""&
 IF(W202="canceled", 0, SPLIT(P202, " ")), "(?i)xxx|yyy"), 0)*1
```

for array try:

```
=INDEX(IF(P202:P="",,MMULT(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(""&
 IF(W202:W="canceled", 0, SPLIT(P202:P, " ")), "(?i)xxx|yyy"), 0)*1, 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(P202:P, " ")), 1, 0
```

Comment: The first option you listed works very well thank you. But I need to have multiple options instead of just cancelled such as cancelled, postponed, dropped. Do you have a resolution for that?

Comment: @MatthewSmith sure. instead of `W202="canceled"` use: `REGEXMATCH(""&W202, "(?i)canceled|postponed|dropped")`